Paint is splitting pearl moulding
I am adding frame moulding to the front of my kitchen cabinets. I have done this in other applications but never with pearl moulding. When I paint the moulding the wood is splitting. It's no longer pearl and more like daggers.
I'm only in my 1st round of cabinets but have to keep using this moulding. For my next round what would be a good way to "seal" the wood and then continue painting?
Pic is of minor splitting. I have done
an atrocious amount of maneuvers to correct the splitting so I don't have any photos of the actual horrors.

Also WHY IS THIS HAPPENING? All moulding has to be painted I can't believe this is only happening to me. I searched the internets....ugh.
Here's another pic. But this is after 1 coat primer, 2 coats paint, plus intermittent sanding jagged edges.



Was the wood primed with a primer that is suitable for the paint you are using?  The pic makes me think the paint is splitting rather than the wood.  Can you post more pics showing exactly where you see splits?

My notion is that an oil-based primer would be better than a water-based one. Look forward to hearing what you used.

Great point about the oil based primer! I was using water based but assumed it was my only option for the SW proclassic. SW said an oil based primer will work tho. I will test a batch and see if it splits.

Yeah, unless the wood was really wet (doubtful for molding) it's more likely the paint.
